# [htaccess]Loading Angularjs for browsers And SSR for bots

Tags: angular, .htaccess, server-side-rendering

I came up with my own solution to solve my problem of SEO and other bots rendering my web (like some social bots whatsapp bot, facebook bot, twitter bot etc). I created identical routes in the backend using ejs (nodejs) to serves html pages with meta tags pre rendered. I want all bots to renders the server html files but for the browsers, i want to load the angular app.

This is the .htaccess i am currently using to server only my angular app

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

How can i achieve the required results?

Comment: Why don't you use Angular Universal? There are really good starter repos around... for example: https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter

Comment: My app is built using angular 1. The link you have shared is using angular 5/6 mate.

Comment: Oh, that didn't turned out from your question. Angular 2+ is called Angular, Angular 1 usually called AngularJS

Comment: Okay I have updated my question. I am trying to solve it by myself. I will add an answer if i could

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [vinceMeens](https://gist.github.com/thoop/8072354#gistcomment-982286), i was able to solve my problem with the following htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    # Go to it as is
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|Whatsapp|whatsapp|outbrain|pinterest|googlebot|bingbot|yandex|showyoubot|outbrain|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator  [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/api/" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```